# Master - Detail project not working as expected

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uisplitviewcontroller

Using the default project from xcode for a master-detail application, if i place a `print` debug statement in the collapse delegate, it never seems to get triggered when i rotate the device (in fact i can't get it too trigger ever).

The bit of code i've edited is in AppDelegate.swift and looks like this

```
func splitViewController(_ splitViewController: UISplitViewController, collapseSecondary secondaryViewController:UIViewController, onto primaryViewController:UIViewController) -> Bool {

    print("XXXXXXX")

    guard let secondaryAsNavController = secondaryViewController as? UINavigationController else { return false }
    guard let topAsDetailController = secondaryAsNavController.topViewController as? DetailViewController else { return false }
    if topAsDetailController.detailItem == nil {
        // Return true to indicate that we have handled the collapse by doing nothing; the secondary controller will be discarded.
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

and as you can see the delegate is set correctly as per the default project:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    let splitViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UISplitViewController
    let navigationController = splitViewController.viewControllers[splitViewController.viewControllers.count-1] as! UINavigationController
    navigationController.topViewController!.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem
    splitViewController.delegate = self
    return true
}
```

The only thing changed from the default project is that `print("XXXXXXX")` line i've added.

It's my understanding that when it collapses the split view (i.e. due to rotation from landscape to portrait) it should call this delegate method to work out which detail view to use... However it never calls that delegate method.

Am i just not getting how this works or is the default project itself broken?

My end goal is too make it so the master view (on the left) becomes the primary view when it collapses if the detail view has a certain variable set to nil. Getting this (and other delegate methods) to trigger I guess is the first stage of achieving this.

Comment: It calls that method when you are running the app in split screen mode and make the window small enough to force it into the compact width size class.  It isn't related to the hiding/showing of the master view due to display mode changes.

Comment: @dan I guess i'm just trying to take it back to basics to build off it from there. What i'm trying to do is simply get that method to trigger. Rotating the device from landscape to portrait forces it to go into compact width size class (master view is hidden), however that delegate function is never called (no debug `XXXXXX` in the log). Shouldn't that method be called when it collapses?

Comment: Unless you have your iPad running in split screen mode with two apps running, then no rotating the device to portrait does not force it to go into the compact width size class.  The `displayMode` (.primaryHidden vs. .allVisible, vs. .primaryOverlay) is a completely separate thing from whether or not the split view is collapsed.

Comment: @dan Oh so that method is purely for split screen multitasking, not when the UISplitView changes from master/detail to just detail?

Comment: Yes, the collapsing/expanding/separating delegate methods are for size class changes, not display mode changes.

Comment: @dan So i need to use a delegate method for when the display mode changes, not when the size class (collapsing) happens! Well now i feel silly, thanks for the help! (i can't mark a comment as accepted answer, could you make an answer saying i'm a newb and too use display mode delegate methods so i can accept it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The delegate methods concerning collapsing/expanding/separating are called during size class changes that happen during split screen multitasking on iPad or when using a split view controller on iPhone.

Hiding/showing the master view controller is a result of the split view controller's `displayMode` changing which you can react to in the `splitViewController:willChangeToDisplayMode:` delegate method.